# SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number (when updating sysdate)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with inventory of items inside and i want to update the date which is expired already with the system date. But its getting error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
update AMU_POHEAD_T SET TGL_TIBA=trunc(sysdate)
 WHERE KD_STORE='1400' AND FAKTUR=:Factor and no_lpb is null
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

This is my script:

```
update AMU_POHEAD_T SET TGL_TIBA=trunc(sysdate)
 WHERE KD_STORE='1400' AND FAKTUR=:Factor and no_lpb is null;
```

`TGL_TIBA` is the Date column. I use SQL Developer. I tried already googling but it gives a different answers.

Comment: Can you add the datatypes of other columns in the query as well?

Comment: KD_STORE is VARCHAR2(4 BYTE), FAKTUR is VARCHAR2(15 BYTE) and no_lpb is VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)...here it is and thanks :)

Comment: And what is the input to :factor?

Comment: Which datatype is `TGL_TIBA`

Comment: Can you add the ful table create statement?

Comment: KD_STORE is VARCHAR2(4 BYTE), FAKTUR is VARCHAR2(15 BYTE) and no_lpb is VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), TGL_TIBA datatype is DATE.. the :factor input is 000000000039746..tnx for replying..

Comment: Is your `factor` bind variable declared as a varchar2 or as a number? The only way I can see you'd get that is if you have it as a number and you have non-numeric values in your table for `faktur`; then you'd get implicit conversion of the column values, which could get this error.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see you getting this error with the table structure you described is if your `factor` bind variable is declared as a number and you have values in your `faktur` column that have non-numeric characters - which is reasonable as it's a string:

```
create table AMU_POHEAD_T (
  KD_STORE VARCHAR2(4 BYTE),
  FAKTUR VARCHAR2(15 BYTE),
  NO_LPB VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  TGL_TIBA DATE
);

insert into AMU_POHEAD_T values ('1400', '000000000039746', null, sysdate - 30);
insert into AMU_POHEAD_T values ('1400', 'A00000000039746', null, sysdate - 30);

variable factor number;

exec :factor := '000000000039746';

update AMU_POHEAD_T SET TGL_TIBA=trunc(sysdate)
 WHERE KD_STORE='1400' AND FAKTUR=:Factor and no_lpb is null;

SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

If `factor` is a number then column values will be implicitly converted to numbers for comparison, and trying to convert a non-numeric value with throw that error - e.g. the implicit `to_number('A00000000039746')` here.

If `factor` is a string then that conversion doesn't happen:

```
var factor varchar2(15 byte);

exec :factor := '000000000039746';

update AMU_POHEAD_T SET TGL_TIBA=trunc(sysdate)
 WHERE KD_STORE='1400' AND FAKTUR=:Factor and no_lpb is null;

1 rows updated.
```

Comment: @ Alex Poole, Thank you for the explanation and now I understand. The cause of the error is because I have a non-numeric character in my column(the FAKTUR column)? because I have data inside like this " 000000000039746
1438-R-G14-0016
1438-R-G14-0015
1438-R-G14-0014
000000000000082
000000000000083" under the FAKTUR column. How to make it runnable even if I have this kind of data inside? What is the correct script? Then I just want to ask, when I use **TOAD** with this script there's no problem, it works fine, unlike in **SQL Developer** its getting error. Pls help..Thanks

Comment: I made also a new table **test1** with the same values inside with  **amu_pohead_t** and datatype and follow your instruction but still same error result using bind.

Comment: @raymundsumaylo - my example in the answeris from SQL Developer, but giving the bind value with `variable` and running as a script; are you running as a statement and being prompted for the value? If so which version are you using? It sounds like it's guessing the variable type from the value.

Comment: @raymundsumaylo - yes, confirmed that you get the error if you enter the value in the "enter binds" dialog when running as a statement. There isn't any way to specify the bind variable type (which I believe you can do in Toad). I don't see a way to get around this when running it as a statement; you can avoid the error with concatenation or `cast(:Factor as varchar2(15 byte))` but then it won't match as you lose the leading zeros. Running as a script (F5) with the code above works though. If that isn't acceptable, maybe raise it on the SQL Developer forum.

Comment: @ Alex Poole - I used Oracle SQL Deveoper  Version 4.0.0.12, yes it prompted for  the value..Thank you for the help and explanation now I understand clearly. :)